# Need help reading a grep/sed/regex statement

Tags: regex, bash, sed, scripting, grep

Can someone please take the following statements:

```
kernelHash=$(grep -m 1 -o '"uImage-[0123456789.]*-ts-armv7l": [^, }]*' $SecureBootJson | sed 's/^.*: //')

kernelHash=$(grep -oP '"uImage-[0123456789.]*-ts-armv7l.*?\btype\b"' $SecureBootJson | cut -f3 -d ' ' | sed 's/,//')
```

and break them down for me and explain what they are supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Match `"uImage-`, followed by any number of characters present in the set of `0123456789.`, followed by `-ts-armv7l": `, followed by any number of characters present in the set `^, }` **AND** Match `"uImage-`, followed by any number of characters present in the set of `0123456789.`, followed by `-ts-armv7l`, followed by any number of non-newline characters (but as few as possible until the next token is matched), followed by a word boundary (`(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)` without consuming a character), followed by `type`, followed by another word boundary and finally by `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are setting a variable `kernelHash` based on the value of the file whose name/path is stored in the variable `$SecureBootJson`. I will assume you understand what the pipes `|` are doing.

### Grep

[`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) helps us parse the arguments to grep:

- `-m 1`: Stop reading a file after 1 matching line
- `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line
- `-P`: Interpret the regex as a Perl regex

#### Grep regexes

```
'"uImage-[0123456789.]*-ts-armv7l": [^, }]*'
```

Matches a `"key": value` pair

1. `"uImage-`: literally
2. `[0123456789.]*`: zero or more digits or dots
3. `-ts-armv7l":`: literally
4. `[^, }]*`: zero or more characters that are not `,`, or `}`

and

```
'"uImage-[0123456789.]*-ts-armv7l.*?\btype\b"'
```

Matches a "quoted" string

1. `"uImage-`: literally
2. `[0123456789.]*`: zero or more digits or dots
3. `-ts-armv7l`: literally
4. `.*?`: [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) matches zero or more non-newline characters
5. `\btype\b"`: Matches the word 'type' using [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

### cut

```
cut -f3 -d ' '
```

From [`man cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

- `-f3`: return the 3rd field
- `-d ' '`: split on single spaces

So this cut command splits the string on spaces and returns the 3rd section.

### The sed commands

```
sed 's/^.*: //'
```

Replaces all non-newline characters between the beginning of the line the rightmost ': ' with nothing. Assuming the `grep` left us with a `"key": value` line where `value` does not contain ': '(which it cannot thanks to grep), we are left with `value`.

```
sed 's/,//'
```

Replaces the first `,` found in the string with nothing.

### Note

There are a number of quirks and opportunities for improvement in these commands, but I have not included them in the main body of the answer, because the question was "what does this do?". My foremost suggestion would be the use of `jq` to parse Json.

Comment: `.*: ` is greedy, so it would replace everything up until the last `: ` in the line.  Not really important here, but it does make the `^` anchor at the beginning of the line unnecessary.  Something like `^[^:]*: ` would make more sense.

Comment: A very thorough explanation!  And helpful.  Thanks Will.